# Proxy Server for ubuntu!

Tags: server

i tried using finch vpn and many other things.But they wont provide a proxy server as the network is blocked by security. Even i tried installing psiphon through vine but it wont work. any suggestions.thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what other proxy servers you have used and of course there are lots of proxy servers for Ubuntu.But i have used [Squid](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/squid.html) and it really works.I have also use **Tor Browser** that is installed in your Ubuntu by default and it works perfectly for me.I have used another proxy server called [uproxy](https://www.uproxy.org/) that is an extension for chrome and firefox and it works good too.Let me know if these three don't work for you and what kind of problems you have with them.